# how to use two tableviews using button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

i want to use two tableviews like…..

i am using popover controller

first tableview is in the popover controller
in that  popover controller i have two buttons(add notes button  and remainder button)
when i click on the remainder button i am hiding the first tableview and enabling the second tableview

ut for the second tableview cellforrowatindexpath is not calling

only for  the first tableview it is calling,not calling for the second table view

here my code is………..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (tableView==self.remainderTableView)//second Tbleview {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Celliden";
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
           cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }

        cell.textLabel.text=@"hhh";
        return cell;

    }
    else if (tableView==self.NotesandRemainderTable)//first Tableview {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"bookingCell";

   CustomTableViewSwipeCell *cell = (CustomTableViewSwipeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *note=[jsondata valueForKey:@"TeacherNotes"];

        NSLog(@"teacher notes %@",note);
        //    if (cell==nil) {
        //        cell=[[CustomTableViewSwipeCell alloc]init];
        //    }
        // Add utility buttons

        NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];


        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                                    title:@"Delete"];

        _SubjectLabel.text=AppDel.sub;
        NSLog(@"the date %@",AppDel.date);
        _DateLabel.text=_dateToDisplay;
        if (indexPath.section==0)
        {
            if (indexPath.row==0)
            {
                cell.Noteslabel.text=note;



            }


            return cell;

        }
        if (indexPath.section==1){

            cell.Noteslabel.text=[_notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            //NSLog(@"notes index %@",[notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            cell.rightUtilityButtons = rightUtilityButtons;
            cell.delegate=self;
            return cell;


        }
    }
          //cell.rightUtilityButtons = rightUtilityButtons;
   return nil;

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView==self.NotesandRemainderTable) {
        if (section==0) {
            return 1;
        }

        else if (section==1) {

            if (leanerNots==nil || [leanerNots isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                return 0;
            }
            else{

                return [_notesArray count];
            }

        }

    }else{
        return 3;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

//This my remainder button code......

```
 -(IBAction)addRemainderAction:(id)sender{
    self.lineLabel.hidden=NO;
    self.remainderTableView.hidden=NO;
    self.addButtonObj.hidden=NO;
    //self.remainderTableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 62, 300, 321);

    //[self.view addSubview:self.remainderTableView];
    self.NotesandRemainderTable.hidden=YES;
    self.notesBtnObj.hidden=YES;
    self.remainderBtnObj.hidden=YES;
     _SubjectLabel.hidden=YES;

}
```

Can any one help to solve this bug...i am new to Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the datasource and delegate of your second tableview?

for example in viewDidLoad:

```
self.remainderTableView.datasource = self;
self.remainderTableView.delegate = self;
```

And you probably want to reload your tableviews before they are displayed. To do so use the following code for your second tableview

```
[self.remainderTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: did you add the reloadData method too? in addRemainderAction

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear from this code whether you have set the `delegate` and `dataSource` correctly for both `UITableView` instances. If you have not, then these delegate methods will never get called.

Regardless, this case might be better handled by using two data sets instead of two tableViews. Implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the same way you are now, except instead of creating your cell conditionally based on the value of `tableView`, just use the value of your `UIButton`. Two `UITableViews` seems like overkill for this situation when the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods allow you to source from different data sets easily already.